# unsupported operand types in form.inc drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

[image]

[image]

On click of My hello page, I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in D:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\form.inc on line 1814

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: this link can help :https://www.drupal.org/node/2181367

Comment: post code not the image of code .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass arguments in your hello_showhelloForm() function..
Like this
hello_showhelloForm($form, &$form_state){}

Answer (score 0):

your Funtion Hello_showHello_form() should be like this

```
function Hello_showHelloform(){
$form = array();
$form['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
'#title' => t('Enter your Name'),
);
retrun $form;
}
```

Need # before type.